# c# how to put several groups of words from textfile into arrays

Tags: c#, string, parsing, text, text-files

i have a textfile containing these kind of words

```
PEOPLE
John
0218753458
ENTERPRISE
stock
30%
HOME
Indiana
West Virginia
PEOPLE
Vahn
031245678
ENTERPRISE
Inc
50%
HOME
melbourne
Australia
```

i want to split these files into some strings that will divide the into each groups of PEOPLE, ENTERPRISE, and HOME. for example the output will be

part[0]

```
 PEOPLE
 John
 0218753458
```

part[1]

```
ENTERPISE
stock
30%
```

part[2]

```
HOME
Indiana
West Virginia
```

and so on

i have a plan of using

EDIT #1 (thanks @Slade)

```
string[] part = s.Split(new string[] { "PEOPLE","ENTERPRISE","HOME" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
```

i can't change the structure.
is there any way to keep the HEADER? or better way to do this?

Comment: That is not the correct way to create an array of strings. Start by replacing the || with , (commas), and your code will at least be compiling.

Comment: In your example output, what has happened to the second set of data, i.e. Vahn, melbourne etc.? Are you expecting this data to be inserted into the same array?

Comment: no, it will aslo be part[3],part[4],part[5]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using regex and because you want to keep the split strings in the results:

```
string[] tmp = Regex.Split(originalString, @"(PEOPLE|ENTERPRISE|HOME)");

List result = new List();
for(var i = 1; i < tmp.Count() - 1; i += 2) {
    result.Add(tmp[i] + tmp[i+1]);
}
```

This gives you the result you want.

The reason why I'm concatenating the tmp array is because as of .NET 2.0, the Regex.Split will return the split strings as part of the array.  I also start the indexing at 1 because we want our concatenation to happen late

Answer (score 2):

Don't use the [`||`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/6373h346%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) operator, that's for conditional/logical OR expressions. Instead, when filling elements of an array like you are doing, use a comma, like so:

```
string[] part = s.Split(new string[] { "PEOPLE", "ENTERPRISE", "HOME" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
```

However, unless you are *always* going to have these headings, it is not a good way of trying to split your text file. Instead, you need to define some structure to your file. For example, if you are always going to have headers in FULL CAPS, then you may want to start by splitting your text file into lines, then looping through each element and group the elements each time you hit a line containing only characters in FULL CAPS.

Personally, if possible, I would change the text file structure so you can flag headers with some symbol before or after: e.g. `:THIS IS A HEADER`. That way, you can split into lines then just look for the `:` symbol at the start of a line.

**EDIT**

For a sample approach on how to go about parsing this with the FULL CAPS headers, see my code example on [PasteBin](http://pastebin.com/Hm4unk2N).

Note: The line ...

```
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(@"Sample.txt");
```

... could be replaced with ...

```
string textFromFile = File.ReadAllText(@"Sample.txt");
string[] lines = textFromFile.Split(new string[1] { System.Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Comment: ah yes thank you, but is there any way i don't lose the header words for PEOPLE, ENTERPRISE and HOME?

Comment: i can't change the text file structure, but it's always use FULL CAPS, so if possible i would like to split these file or is there any better way to do this? using regex perhaps? or substring?

Comment: @GammaSatriaKurniawan See my edited answer for a possible approach.

Comment: yes certainly it's great help, but your code save each line in an array for themselves, what i need is it save them in an array for each group, maybe i could edit some of your code, thanks

Comment: Ah sorry i missed the debug i just see the lines >.<, thanks Slade but still i can't find the exact solution

Comment: @GammaSatriaKurniawan Using my example, you should be able to find a modified approach that will achieve exactly what you want. My example was merely a suggested approach that incorporated the solution I was trying to explain.

Answer (score 0):

```
s.Split(new string[] {"PEOPLE", "ENTERPRISE", ... }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

And if you want save headers itself than possiblle it will be preferable to split your string multiple times by each arguments and add header by hands. For example you split your string by People and add people header to each chunk. Then split each chunk by HOME and add HOME header by hands and so on.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to give an answer that doesn't exactly match up with what you've asked for, so if you're dead set on having the output you've defined in your question then please disregard. Otherwise, I hope this is useful;

```
var peopleList = new List<string>();
var enterpriseList = new List<string>();
var homeList = new List<string>();
List<string> workingList = null;

using (var reader = new StreamReader("input.txt"))
{
    string line = reader.ReadLine();
    while (line != null)
    {
        switch (line)
        {
            case "PEOPLE": { workingList = peopleList; } break;
            case "ENTERPRISE": { workingList = enterpriseList; } break;
            case "HOME": { workingList = homeList; } break;

            default: { workingList.Add(line); } break;
        }

        line = reader.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Based on your sample input, this will populate three lists as follows;

```
peopleList = { "John", "0218753458", "Vahn", "031245678" }
enterpriseList = { "stock", "30%", "Inc", "50%" }
homeList = { "Indiana", "West Virginia", "melbourne", "Australia" }
```